# how to pass values from multiple ListView to Datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, listview, datagridview

I have 2 `listviews` and a `datagridview`.

One listview has 3 columns `ProductCode,ProductName,ProductPrice` and the second listview has two columns `Godown Name,Godown Code`.

When I click on `datagridview`'s first column `product` i want the `listview visible` and i want to then pass the `listview`'s selected values to the `datagridview` in the same sequence.

When I click on the `godown` column in datagridview the `godown listview` should become visible and then pass the slected value of `godown listview` to the `godown` column in `datagridview`. How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that might help:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 1; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }

    }

    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Decide which column corresponds to the one clicked
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                FillColumn(listView2, 0, e.ColumnIndex);
                break;
            case 1:
                FillColumn(listView1, 1, e.ColumnIndex);
                break;
            case 2:
                FillColumn(listView2, 1, e.ColumnIndex);
                break;
            case 3:
                FillColumn(listView1, 0, e.ColumnIndex);
                break;
            case 4:
                FillColumn(listView1, 2, e.ColumnIndex);
                break;
        }
    }
    //Take the corresponding listview, the listview column, and the dgv column
    //and populate the dgv with the listview data
    private void FillColumn(ListView lv, int lvcolumn, int dgvcolumn)
    {
        lv.Visible = true;            
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[lvi.Index].Cells[dgvcolumn].Value = lvi.SubItems[lvcolumn].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It tries to do what the OP asked, with explanations included. duh